# How to read firebase database with multiple datatypes under the same node?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app which uses Firebase for most of its work. I have designed the database really poorly. The database has a child called notes. In this notes child, there are values under their own unique keys. But, there are various types of values such as string, int, boolean, and custom objects. Can you please explain me how I can filter out the data of a single desired data type? Here is a sample of my database:

```
notes
|
|_ -KdewVsTSBw5dse
|   |
|   |_ Quantity: 1
|
|_ -KshwXbhwhbHSYsC:
|   |
|   |_ Name: "Shubham"
|
|_ -KshwwndwHDWQsqjs:
|   |
|   |_ Date: "25/06/17"
|
|_ -KssfnejrwSBHJWwj:
|   |
|   |_ Done: true
```

For example, I want to read all the data of String data type in this notes child, how can I do it, because if I use dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) it throws an error when encountering other data types.

Comment: What's the problem? As in: what did you try and what problem did that give? By providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you're most likely to get help with this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use try catch inside the `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` method and you will be getting all data with String.class